# Android SQLCipher RC4 encrypted database file "file is encrypted or is not a database"

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I have an encyprted SQLite database file that is being exported from an existing application using System.Data.SQLite.  Based on what I can find, System.Data.SQLite uses 128-bit RC4 encryption.

When I try to load this database in my Android application with SQLCipher, I get the following error "file is encrypted or is not a database".  I have tried using a database hook which sets the pragma key = rc4, but this does not seem to help.  The only program I have been able to find that can open this database file is [SQLite2009 Pro Enterprise Manager](http://osenxpsuite.net/download.htm).  It opens it with no issue, allows me to browse, and run queries.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
        try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(activity);

        //this function copies the db file from the project assets to the data/databases folder
        copydatabase();

        File databaseFile = activity.getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("someDB.db3");

        SQLiteDatabaseHook hook = new SQLiteDatabaseHook(){
            public void preKey(SQLiteDatabase database){
                database.execSQL("pragma cipher = rc4");
            }
            public void postKey(SQLiteDatabase database){
                database.execSQL("pragma cipher = rc4");
            }
        };

        SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databaseFile.getAbsolutePath(), "mypassword", null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS|SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, hook);

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;", null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SOME_COLUMN"));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(ex.getMessage().toString(), ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got an answer over on the [SQLCipher Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/4nu_qbW8TOw):

> If your SQLite database was encrypted outside of SQLCipher, you will 
>   first need to export that database to a plain-text SQLite database. 
>   Once you have done that you can use the sqlcipher_export convenience 
>   function to create an SQLCipher encrypted version your plain-text 
>   database.  Please refer to example 1 [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/4nu_qbW8TOw) in the documentation for 
>   sqlcipher_export for your scenario.
>
> http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api#sqlcipher_export

Answer (score 0):

Your database may be of an older SQLCipher version than the one you are trying to open it with.

Try to execute the query `PRAGMA cipher_migrate;` just after opening and setting the key of the database.